# My hard disc makes a clicking noise while I'm working, I sent it to a service which found nothing

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive

He said that there was no problem with the hdd. He checked it out with crystalnfo and it worked. But before I took it there,the pc wasn't turning on. He said that there was a problem with the system because it was windows xp and it has expired. My pc is dual core 2.4Ghz,ram 1gb (890 mb useble). I'm not pretty sure it has no problem with hard disc.

Comment: If your HDD is making mechanical clicking sounds, then despite what the firmware indicates, you have a drive that has started to fail.  In other words you need to replace the HDD.

Comment: The easiest way to tell the state of the HDD for sure, is to boot from a Ubuntu Live CD, and use the "Disk Utility" applet to check the health of the disk. It should be able to tell you whether the disk is mechanically functional.

Comment: A clicking sound coming from the HDD can be a sign that the HDD isn't getting enough power or it might mean that the HDD is failing. Whatever the reason make sure to backup all your important data to an external HDD. You can try booting into a Ubuntu Live CD to check if you'll be able to copy your data. Another thing you could do is test the HDD in a different PC.

Comment: He took my hdd and tested it in another pc and it worked.He said there was no problem with the hdd and he was sure 100% there wasn't.He copied my data to another disc and.So i upgraded +1gb RAM and put windows 7.13 Days later my pc works but fails sometimes.It makes that noise sometimes but he hardly startup with startup repair.

Answer (score 1):

He is talking crap.  Windows XP has not expired - its simply no longer supported (for most people).  Even if it had "expired", the PC would still start, the OS might not load and might throw an error though.

There are [*plenty* of systems in the world still running XP.](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/07/02/windows_7_and_81_market_share_surge_xp_falls_behind_os_x/)   (about 10% as at end of June 2015  according to this link) - only slightly less then desktops running the Mac OS system - OSX

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the integrated windows disk checking tool by opening the command prompt and entering "chkdsk /f /r". Press Y when prompted, reboot your computer, and wait for the disk check to complete during the bootup.

When it boots up, open command prompt again and enter just "chkdsk". When the quick check finishes, you should see in the report if there are any bad sectors. If bad sectors are not mentioned, or if there are 0 blocks in bad sectors, than it should be OK.

Additionally, you could download a separate tool linke this one:
http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm

It will check your disk for errors and reliability using SMART (self-monitoring analysis and reporting technology).

And of course, backup your data regularly!